# NFS file share problem Debian

Tags: debian, nfs

`sudo apt-get install nfs-kernel-server`
I have my `/etc/expots` file here;

`/mnt/extHD 192.168.1.0/24(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)`

I have restarted all the services and set ufw to allow nfs, yet when I do a

`sudo showmount -e localhost`

I get;

`clnt_create: RPC: program not registered`

Comment: I'm on Debian. I should have said that

Comment: etc expots wont work  (typo?) and debian also needs rpcbind